# Laravel :How to send emails to email addresses which are inside the database using a button

Tags: laravel, email

I have a table in the database called users and it has columns id, name, email 
what I wanted to do is when I'm clicking it should send an email to a specific user recognized by the id

I have a table structure of user data named checkin.blade.php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysd0G.png)

I have the mail template too how can I work with the routes and the controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Route::get('/send-email/{user}', 'YourController@sendEmail');


<a href='/send-email/{{$user->id}}'><button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button></a>


//in controller

public function sendEmail(User $user){

  Mail::to($user->email)->send(new YourMailTemplate());
  return back();
}
```

Your route can take advantage of route/model binding in Laravel. The button just calls that route with the users id (assuming you're generating stuff in a foreach loop with each user having its own row or div). In your controller, you just send the mail template of your choice after the method takes in the User model with its included email address as a parameter. You also want to make sure you're "using" the "Mail" and the "YourMailTemplate" in the top of the controller file:

```
use App\Mail\YourMailTemplate;
use Mail;
```